# Shell script - get current date with a fixed time element in ‘seconds since epoch’ format

Tags: bash, shell

I’m fairly new to Linux and shell scripting so I hope that you will forgive a nooby question.

I want to get the current date **but with a fixed time** into a variable with the value in epoch seconds.

I have done this so far, but I’m really not happy with it:

```
startTime=$(date -d $(date +”%FT03:15:00”) +%s)
```

It works ok but just seems a bit clunky (mainly because of the two calls to `date`) so was wondering if there is a better/cleaner way to achieve what I’m after?

I tried a `printf` alternative which cut down on one date call but…

The jobs that’s running this isn’t performance critical but I like to code for efficiency out of habit.

Comment: `date` is smart enough to understand that if you say 03:15:00 without specifying the full date, that means today. So `date -d 03:15:00 +%s` might be what you want

Comment: Perfect! Works exactly how I wanted, is more concise and efficient. Many thanks

Comment: FWIW, it's `"newbie"` (or just `NB`), not `"nooby"`. Welcome to StackOverflow.